# C++, Convert OADate to struct tm

Tags: c++, winapi, datetime

Excel dates are stored as double in a convention that seems to be called `OADate`, is there a built-in function to convert the `OADate` to a `struct tm`.

For example, in Excel, the `9/May/2014` is `41768`. I need in C++ to find a way to convert `41768` in a `struct tm` initialised to the correct date.

Are there built-in functions to do this ? I could use `VariantTimeToSystemTime()` but it converts it to a `LPSYSTEMTIME` which needs then to be converted into a `struct tm`. I was looking for something that would do both at the same time. It is not very hard to do but I would rather use built-in functions than writing my own.

Comment: I doubt there is something like this - the Windows APIs are not known for their compatibility with standard C/C++. If I were you, I think I'd write a utility function that uses `VariantTimeToSystemTime` internally and outputs/fills a `struct tm`.

Answer (score 1):

In the case someone needs to do it, this is enough to make it work:

```
    double oaDate = 41678.;
    char buffer[256];
    struct tm timeinfo;
    _SYSTEMTIME lpSystemTime;
    VariantTimeToSystemTime(oaDate, &lpSystemTime);
    timeinfo.tm_mday = lpSystemTime.wDay;
    timeinfo.tm_mon = lpSystemTime.wMonth - 1;      // Be careful of different conventions
    timeinfo.tm_year = lpSystemTime.wYear - 1900;
    timeinfo.tm_hour = lpSystemTime.wHour;
    timeinfo.tm_min = lpSystemTime.wMinute;
    timeinfo.tm_sec = lpSystemTime.wSecond;
    timeinfo.tm_isdst = 0;
    mktime(&timeinfo);
```